# TypeError: ansiColors.create is not a function at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, angular, build, angular8, angularbuild

Help me to resolve following angular build issue

```
ng build --configuration=qa


/opt/tomcat/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_14.15.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js:22
const colors = ansiColors.create();
                      ^

TypeError: ansiColors.create is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/tomcat/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_14.15.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js:22:27)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/tomcat/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS_14.15.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js:15:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: what version of node.js do you have ?

Comment: try to upgrate/downgrade node version

Comment: I had a same problem and what helped is deleting node modules folder and installing it again.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue today and also using Jenkins. I solved it by removing `node_modules` directory.

Previous script:

```
(cd client/ && npm install)
(cd client/ && npm run build)
```

New script:

```
(cd client/ && rm -r node_modules)
(cd client/ && npm install)
(cd client/ && npm run build)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you look into `./node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/color.js` you gonna find this sentence

```
 // Typings do not contain the function call (added in Node.js v9.9.0)
```

So the solution is to have a node.js version of at least v9.9.0

Comment: I have same problem and have version v15.11.0. I would not agree that solution is to have node version at least v9.9.0.

Comment: Same i have node v10 and it still doesn't work